Xamarin - Error in Azure pipeline while building
I am working on a Xamarin project and we have the code on Azure.
I would like to run pipeline but ending up with following error.
    ##[error]R8(0,0): Error : Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
         5>R8 : error : Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest [D:\a\1\s\myGAS.Agent.Mobile\my.Project.Android\my.Project.Mobile.Android.csproj]
    ##[error]R8(0,0): Error : Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
         5>R8 : error : Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest [D:\a\1\s\my.Project.Mobile\my.Project.Mobile.Android\my.Project.Mobile.Android.csproj]
    ##[error]R8(0,0): Error : Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
         5>R8 : error : Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage [D:\a\1\s\my.Project.Mobile\myGAS.Agent.Mobile.Android\my.Project.Mobile.Android.csproj]
             Compilation failed
             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
                at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:98)
                at com.android.tools.r8.R8.main(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:4)
[CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage]

I have also tried to add the below in AndroidManifest.xml but did not work
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

Please someone help to resolve this.
